# $ helm version gives "Cannot connect to tiller"

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, kubernetes-helm

I created a kubernetes cluster 3 using vagrant machines and installed helm. But when checking the version of helm it gives the version of client and says "cannot connect to tiller. 
I can't install any chart using helm due to an error related to forwarding ports.

```
vagrant@master:~$ helm init

$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/vagrant/.helm.
Warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster.
(Use --client-only to suppress this message, or --upgrade to upgrade Tiller to the current version.)
Happy Helming!

vagrant@master:~$ helm version

Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.6.2", GitCommit:"be3ae4ea91b2960be98c07e8f73754e67e87963c", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: cannot connect to Tiller

vagrant@master:~$ helm install nginx

Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist
```

I found a solution here :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/troubleshooting/

This is caused by the API load balancer not forwarding ports in the context of the helm client-server relationship.

But the procedure to solve the error is not clear for me.

For example, the first step says to expose the Kubernetes Master service :

```
   juju expose kubernetes-master
```

But i use kubectl instead of juju. So how can i find the name of k8s master service? and how should do this step using kubectl?

In short, I want to do the steps using kubectl, instead of juju.And i don't understand the difference.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you write which steps of the procedure are unclear?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: can you check it now? @RafałLeszko

Comment: I think you can install `juju` and try the steps described. Probably the fastest way to check. Alternatively, you could create an ingress controller with kubectl, but it's the longer solution to test if the link you posted solves the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. I installed juju and but got no luck. Since to installed the cluster with kubectl, we didn't have kubernetes-master at all...

Comment: These errors occurred when Installed Helm in a multi-node cluster. Thus I created a single-node cluster and installed Helm in that cluster. Now Checking the version of the Helm shows both client and server versions.

Comment: Same issue here, I'm googling about a fix but without success.

Comment: Try upgrading your helm version to 3..